# R - Shiny Package - Non-numeric argument to binary operator

Tags: r, shiny

I'm pretty new to using R and I'm just testing out some things with the Shiny package. In my application I request the user to give some inputs, based on these inputs the application has to make some calculations.

The input gets asked from the user in the following way (ui.R code)

```
library(shiny)
shinyUI(fluidPage(
      titlePanel("Shiny Test application"),
      # The layout
      fixedRow(
        column(9,
           radioButtons("data",label = "Data", list("Onbelangrijk", "Minder belangrijk", "Neutraal", "Belangrijk", "Zeer belangrijk"), "", inline = TRUE),
           radioButtons("visualisatie",label = "Visualisation", list("Onbelangrijk", "Minder belangrijk", "Neutraal", "Belangrijk", "Zeer belangrijk"), "", inline = TRUE),
           radioButtons("price",label = "Price", list("Onbelangrijk", "Minder belangrijk", "Neutraal", "Belangrijk", "Zeer belangrijk"), "", inline = TRUE),
           radioButtons("self",label = "Self-service", list("Onbelangrijk", "Minder belangrijk", "Neutraal", "Belangrijk", "Zeer belangrijk"), "", inline = TRUE),
```

Below represents my server.R code.

Example how the values of the input are generated:

```
     data <- reactive({
      if(input$data == "Onbelangrijk") {
        data <- 1
      } else if (input$data == "Minder belangrijk") {
        data <- 3
      } else if (input$data == "Neutraal") {
        data <- 5
      } else if (input$data == "Belangrijk") {
        data <- 7
      } else {
        data <- 9
      } })

visualisatie <- reactive({
    if(input$visualisatie == "Onbelangrijk") {
      visualisatie <- 1
    } else if (input$visualisatie == "Minder belangrijk") {
      visualisatie <- 3
    } else if (input$visualisatie == "Neutraal") {
      visualisatie <- 5
    } else if (input$visualisatie == "Belangrijk") {
      visualisatie <- 7
    } else {
      visualisatie <- 9
    } })
```

The values for price and self get derived in the same way.

Putting this input into a vector:

```
criteria <- c(data, visualisatie, price, self)
```

Generating needed matrix to use AHP formula :

```
  MATR <- matrix(criteria, nrow = 4, ncol = 4)
  MATR2 <- t(t(MATR)/criteria)
```

This results in the following error message:

```
Error in t(MATR)/criteria : non-numeric argument to binary operator
```

I think the error is because of the vector created earlier.
I already tried to use the following functions:

```
criteria <- as.numeric(criteria)
```

and

```
criteria <- as.numeric(unlist(criteria))
```

But those resulted in the following error:

```
(list) object cannot be coerced to type 'double'
```

Another weird thing is that when I execute the code in the R console, all works fine.
However when I use the code in a shiny application, the application crashes with the 'non-numeric argument to binary operator code' error.

Comment: Please [show some data](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). We have no idea what makes up the other variables within `criteria`.

Comment: I hope I provided you with enough information now to understand my problem.

Comment: Is there a time when none of the radioButtons are selected? I know `radioButtons` defaults the first to be `checked`, but perhaps you are changing it externally?

Comment: Radiobuttons are default selected on "neutraal" = value of 5.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using `reactive`, the resulting enclosures need to be called as functions. See [`?reactive`](http://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/latest/reactive.html). Instead use:

```
data <- c(data(), visualisatie(), price(), self())
```

BTW: there are a couple of neater (as in "clean code") methods of doing your conversion:

```
data <- reactive({
    switch(input$data,
           "Onbelangrijk" = 1,
           "Minder belangrijk" = 3,
           "Neutraal" = 5,
           "Belangrijk" = 7,
           9)
    })
## repeat for the other three
```

or perhaps even changing *what* is reactive:

```
MATR <- reactive({
    likert <- function(x) {
        switch(x,
               "Onbelangrijk" = 1,
               "Minder belangrijk" = 3,
               "Neutraal" = 5,
               "Belangrijk" = 7,
               9)
        }
    data <- likert(input$data)
    visualisatie <- likert(input$visualisatie)
    price <- likert(input$price)
    self <- likert(input$self)
    criteria <- c(data, visualisatie, price, self)
    m <- matrix(criteria, nrow=4, ncol=4)
    m / t(m)
})
```

I'm not a shiny ninja, so there is likely a better way to define a function that can be used within the reactive structure instead of redefining it each time (sigh).

If you need `criteria` elsewhere, then perhaps that should be the reactive component, not `MATR`. Over to you.

Comment: Thanks for the neater methods to do my conversion, really helps the readability! When I call the functions as you described I received the following error: Error in .getReactiveEnvironment()$currentContext() : 
  Operation not allowed without an active reactive context. (You tried to do something that can only be done from inside a reactive expression or observer.)

Comment: Yes, everything in Shiny's server.R needs to be done within a reactive expression or a render function, you can't do any data manipulation outside of it, so you would have to create the matrix inside of the variable it will eventually be assigned to, as above. 

If you don't want the matrix redefining itself each time, you can use an `actionButton` in your ui.R, and then put `isolate()` around the reactive objects you don't to constantly redefine. View this page for the intricacies, as it has more space than this comment: https://gist.github.com/wch/9606002

Comment: Alright, thanks for the feedback! Seems like the error is fixed. :) One more question though, as I need to do some more data manipulation calculations. I guess it's best to do these calculations within the reactive expression? At the end I need to pass the result from these calculations from the server.R to ui.R so I can show it to the user. What's the best way to do this then?

Comment: It depends heavily on your intended interaction with the user. Realize that every time the user changes a single radio button and that variable is within a `reactive` block, everything that depends on it (recursively) will be completely recalculated. Some interfaces choose to only do calculations when triggered (e.g., clicking a button) in order to minimize lag and/or flicker.

Answer (score 0):

Have you stepped through and made sure that you are getting the proper data once your reactive expressions are done?

Because the variables you're generating are all using reactive expressions, they are actually also functions in Shiny. So when you are using your if statements, at the end of all of them you have to return the variable for it to be saved into the object. Because you are not doing that, I think what is happening is that you just don't have any data in criteria, it is just a vector of NA or NULL. So something like

```
data <- reactive({
      if(input$data == "Onbelangrijk") {
        data <- 1
      } else if (input$data == "Minder belangrijk") {
        data <- 3
      } else if (input$data == "Neutraal") {
        data <- 5
      } else if (input$data == "Belangrijk") {
        data <- 7
      } else {
        data <- 9
      } 
    data
})
```

Also, where are you doing this matrix creation? Is it within another function in the server.R script? Generally, because these variables are treated as function, when you call them later to assign them to a vector or something of the like, as you are, you have to call them as though they are a function, e.g.:
`criteria<-c(data(),visualisatie(), price(), self())`

Give those a shot if you haven't already.

Comment: I just tested and I receive the proper data output after my reactive expressions are done. I do this matrix by first building MATR (MATR <- matrix(criteria, nrow = 4, ncol = 4)) and then making my needed MATR2 by diving each row of the matrix through my criteria. hen I call the functions as you described I received the following error: Error in .getReactiveEnvironment()$currentContext() : Operation not allowed without an active reactive context. (You tried to do something that can only be done from inside a reactive expression or observer.)